# Is it possible to retrieve all members, including private, from a class in Java using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'd like to be able to write, for example

```
Method[] getMethods(Class<?> c)
```

which would do the same thing as the existing

```
Class.getMethods()
```

but also include private and protected methods.  Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public Method[] getMethods(Class<?> c) {
    List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();
    while (c != Object.class) {
        methods.addAll(Arrays.asList(c.getDeclaredMethods()));
        c = c.getSuperclass();
    }

    return methods.toArray(new Method[methods.size()]);
}
```

To explain:

- [`getDeclaredMethods`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) returns all methods that are declared by a certain class, *but not its superclasses*
- [`c.getSuperclass()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) returns the immediate superclass of the given class
- thus, recursing up the hierarchy, until `Object`, you get all methods
- in case you want to include the methods of `Object`, then let the condition be `while (c != null)`

Comment: Good code. Why do all the way up just below the `Object` class?

Comment: Because generally one wants only _his_ hierarchy. In my updated answer I included a bullet indicating how to include the Object methods as well

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()) instead. Note that unlike `getMethods()`, this *won't* return inherited methods - so if you want everything, you'll need to recurse up the type hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Class.html) describes all the details.